# How to recognized different combination of input speech text for given Grammar in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I have below code to recognize the given input speech.

```
Public speechRecognitionEngine As SpeechRecognitionEngine
Private Sub SpeechRecog()
        Try
            speechRecognitionEngine = New SpeechRecognitionEngine(SpeechRecognitionEngine.InstalledRecognizers()(0))
            AddHandler speechRecognitionEngine.SpeechRecognized, AddressOf engine_SpeechRecognized
            Dim texts As Choices = New Choices()
            texts.Add("HOW")
            texts.Add("ARE")
            texts.Add("YOU")
            Dim wordsList As Grammar = New Grammar(New GrammarBuilder(texts))
            speechRecognitionEngine.LoadGrammar(wordsList)

            speechRecognitionEngine.SetInputToDefaultAudioDevice()
            speechRecognitionEngine.RecognizeAsync(RecognizeMode.Multiple)
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Voice recognition failed")
        End Try
    End Sub
```

' Event for speech recognision

```
Public Sub engine_SpeechRecognized(sender As Object, e As SpeechRecognizedEventArgs)
      usrText.Text = e.Result.Text
End Sub
```

for above code It is recognising the below Speech texts

1. HOW
2. ARE
3. YOU

but how can recognize below combination out of given GRAMMAR

1. HOW ARE
2. HOW ARE YOU
3. YOU ARE HOW
4. ARE YOU HOW
5. ARE HOW YOU
6. YOU HOW ARE
7. HOW YOU ARE

Is it possible to recognize the above speech input using same grammar?

Thank in Advance

Comment: You need Grammar builder validated grammars. A grammar can have two main parts. The Rules grammar (`Grammar.sraxml`) and the speech recognition (main) grammar  (`Grammar.srgxml`). The Main grammar can have a rule where you define a word or combination of words in a `<one-of> </one-of>` block which can be combined with a list of `<item repeat="[range]">[word]</item>` which may come after the `<one-of>` list. These combinations then refer to a `<tag> out._value = "[Rule Name]";</tag>` rule you have defined in the Rules Grammar to create a related vocal output (when needed).

Comment: See this: [Microsoft Grammar Development Tools](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/speech-technologies/hh362855%28v%3doffice.14%29) from the [Microsoft Speech Platform SDK 11 Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/speech-technologies/dd266409%28v%3doffice.14%29). See this page: [Microsoft Speech Platform](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/speech-technologies/hh361572(v%3doffice.14)). Download the SDK, Runtime and the Voices, you'll find Grammar samples and the related tools.